# How do I generate cron expressions from the value read from app settings in c#

Tags: c#, cron, quartz-scheduler

I have below code to execute some job every configured minutes.

```
 int frequencyOfScheduler = int.Parse(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["FrequencyInMinutes"]);

 IJobDetail job = JobBuilder.Create<CleanUpJob>().Build();
 ITrigger trigger = TriggerBuilder.Create()
      .WithIdentity("CleanUpJob", "ScheduledJob")
      .WithCronSchedule("0 0/1 * 1/1 * ? *")//Hardcoded 
      .Build();
      scheduler.ScheduleJob(job, trigger);
```

Currently frequency is hard coded in cron settings as follow

```
      .WithCronSchedule("0 0/1 * 1/1 * ? *")
```

How do I generate cron expression from value read by appsettings?

Comment: Whats stopping you from keeping the cron expression in AppSettings?

Comment: app settings will be edited by non computer background field engineer and leads to mistakes, keeping string like this "0 0/1 * 1/1 * ? *" in app settings will lead to issue.

Comment: why frequencyOfScheduler variable is integer? you wanted to use in cronexpression?